# Instantly not able to delete contents from Calendar

Tags: java, android, android-contentresolver, android-calendar

`I'm facing an issue with the ListView in an Android app where I'm able to delete an event from the listview using a content resolver. The deletion is reflected instantly in the ListView, but when I reopen the ListView, the deleted items start appearing again. The items are only deleted permanently after a few minutes of delay.What could be the issue??

Below is my listview displaying and deletion code as well content resolver code for event reading and deleting

Calendar_ListView.java

```
package com.example.eventhub;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Calendar_ListView extends AppCompatActivity {
    public ArrayList<String> Events_Name = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> temporary = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;

    Utility utility;

    Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.reminder_list_view);

        context = getApplicationContext();
        utility = new Utility(context);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = findViewById(R.id.ListId);
        AnimationDrawable animationDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) relativeLayout.getBackground();
        animationDrawable.setEnterFadeDuration(3500);
        animationDrawable.setExitFadeDuration(5500);
        animationDrawable.start();
        ListView listview = findViewById(R.id.listview);
//        Fetch_EventNames();

//        Log.d("FETCH_ON_CREATE", Events_Name.toString());
//        Log.d("FETCH_ON_CREATE", temporary.toString(  ));
//        Log.d("LISTVIEW", Events_Name.toString());

        arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(Calendar_ListView.this, R.layout.listview_custom_itemview, temporary);

        listview.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Calendar_ListView.this);
                builder.setMessage("Do you want to delete this reminder?")
                        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // Perform delete action here
//                                Utility utility = new Utility();
                                utility.deleteEventByTitle2(context, Events_Name.get(position));
                                Log.d("FETCH", Events_Name.toString());
                                Log.d("FETCH", temporary.toString());
                                arrayAdapter.remove(arrayAdapter.getItem(position));
//                                Events_Name.remove(position);
//                                temporary.remove(position);
//                                arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }
                        })
                        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // User cancelled the dialog
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();
            }
        });

    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Fetch_EventNames();
        Log.d("LISTVIEW", Events_Name.toString());
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    public void Fetch_EventNames(){
//        Utility utility = new Utility();
        utility.readCalendarEvent(context);
        Events_Name.clear();
        temporary.clear();
        ArrayList<String> titles = utility.nameOfEvent;
        ArrayList<String> myEvents = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(String str : titles){
            if(str != null && str.length() > 3 && str.substring(str.length() - 3).equals("_eh")){
                myEvents.add(str);
            }
        }
        Events_Name = myEvents;
        for(String str : Events_Name){
            temporary.add(str.substring(0, str.length()-3));
        }
//        Log.d("REMINDER_MY_EVENTS", myEvents.toString());
    }
}
```

Utility.java

```
package com.example.eventhub;

import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.ContentUris;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.provider.CalendarContract;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Utility {
    public ArrayList<String> nameOfEvent = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> Event_Start_End = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    public ArrayList<String> startDates = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> endDates = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> descriptions = new ArrayList<String>();
    public ArrayList<String> eventIds = new ArrayList<String>();
    ContentResolver resolver;
    public Utility(Context context){
        resolver = context.getContentResolver();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> readCalendarEvent(Context context) {

//        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
        Cursor cursor = resolver
                .query(
                        Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                        new String[]{"calendar_id", "title", "description",
                                "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation"}, null,
                        null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // fetching calendars name
        String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];

        // fetching calendars id
        nameOfEvent.clear();
        startDates.clear();
        endDates.clear();
        descriptions.clear();
        Log.d("UTILITY_OBJ", "SIZE: "+ Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));

        for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {
            String str1="", str2, str3;
//            ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(3);
            nameOfEvent.add(cursor.getString(1));

            if(cursor.getString(3) != null){
                startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(3))));

            }
            if(cursor.getString(4) != null){
                endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));
            }
            descriptions.add(cursor.getString(2));
            CNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        return nameOfEvent;
    }
    public void deleteEventByTitle(Context context, String title) {
//        ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(
                Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                new String[]{"_id"},
                "title=?",
                new String[]{title},
                null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int temp = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
            long id;
            if(temp >= 0) {
                id = cursor.getLong(temp);
                Uri deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, id);
//                int rows = cr.delete(deleteUri, null, null);
                int rows = resolver.delete(deleteUri, null, null);

                Log.d("UTILITY_OBJ", "Rows deleted: " + rows);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Event Successfully Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                Log.d("UTILITY_OBJ", "EVENT ID NOT FOUND");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Event NOT FOUND!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d("UTILITY_OBJ", "EVENT ID NOT FOUND");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Event NOT FOUND!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        cursor.close();
    }

    public String getDate(long milliSeconds) {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(
                "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
        return formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
    }
    public ArrayList<String> readCalendarEvent2(Context context) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(
                Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                new String[]{"_id", "calendar_id", "title", "description",
                        "dtstart", "dtend", "eventLocation"}, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        // fetching calendars name
        String CNames[] = new String[cursor.getCount()];

        // fetching calendars id
        nameOfEvent.clear();
        startDates.clear();
        endDates.clear();
        descriptions.clear();
        eventIds.clear(); // List to store event IDs
        Log.d("UTILITY_OBJ", "SIZE: "+ Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));

        for (int i = 0; i < CNames.length; i++) {
            eventIds.add(cursor.getString(0)); // Add event ID to list
            nameOfEvent.add(cursor.getString(2));
            if(cursor.getString(4) != null){
                startDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(4))));
            }
            if(cursor.getString(5) != null){
                endDates.add(getDate(Long.parseLong(cursor.getString(5))));
            }
            descriptions.add(cursor.getString(3));
            CNames[i] = cursor.getString(2);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        return nameOfEvent;
    }

    public void deleteEventByTitle2(Context context, String title) {
        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(
                Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"),
                new String[]{"_id"},
                "title=?",
                new String[]{title},
                null);

        ArrayList<String> eventsToDelete = new ArrayList<String>();

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            int temp = cursor.getColumnIndex("_id");
            long id;
            if(temp >= 0) {
                id = cursor.getLong(temp);
                eventsToDelete.add(title);
                Uri deleteUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, id);
                int rows = resolver.delete(deleteUri, null, null);

                Log.d("UTILITY_OBJ", "Rows deleted: " + rows);
                Toast.makeText(context, "Event Successfully Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else {
                Log.d("UTILITY_OBJ", "EVENT ID NOT FOUND");
                Toast.makeText(context, "Event NOT FOUND!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            Log.d("UTILITY_OBJ", "EVENT ID NOT FOUND");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Event NOT FOUND!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        cursor.close();

        // remove eventsToDelete from nameOfEvent ArrayList
        for (String event : eventsToDelete) {
            nameOfEvent.remove(event);
        }
    }


}
```

I tried making a single instance of content resolver but still didn't do any good.`

Comment: You are using the CalendarContract content provider to read and delete events from the device's calendar. When you delete an event using the ContentResolver's delete() method, the event is not immediately deleted from the calendar provider. Instead, it is marked for deletion, and the actual deletion is performed by the provider's background process at some point in the future. This is done to ensure that the event is removed from all synced calendars and that any associated reminders or notifications are also removed.

Comment: So I cannot delete instantly i have to wait after giving delete command?